# Narrow ideal classes and (totally) positive elements

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am trying to understand [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-283-01/S0002-9947-1984-0735415-0/S0002-9947-1984-0735415-0.pdf) paper of D. I. Wallace on conjugation of integer matrices by $SL_n \Bbb Z$, cited in [these](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf) notes by K. Conrad about the Latimer-MacDuffee theorem.

Let $I$ and $J$ be two fractional ideals of an order $O$ in a number field $K$. In both references, $I$ and $J$ are said to be *narrowly equivalent* if $J = rI$ for some element $r \in K$ of positive norm. The equivalence classes arising from this relation are denominated *narrow-ideal classes* and the amount of such classes in defined as the *narrow-class number*.

On the other hand, the narrow class group $Cl^+(O)$ is defined by the relation $I \sim J$ if $J = r I$ for a *totally positive* element $r$, i.e., an element such that $\sigma(r) > 0$ for each real embedding $\sigma \colon K \to \Bbb R$. The equivalence classes of this relation are also called narrow-ideal classes.

> Are these two definition of narrowly equivalent the same? That is, given an element of positive norm $r$, is there a totally positive element $s$ such that $r I = s I$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Take a totally real cubic number field; then $rI = sI$ is
equivalent with $(r) = (s)$, i.e., $r$ and $s$ differ by a unit. This is impossible if the unit group modulo $-1$ consists of totally positive units.

Comment: At the end, "totally real units" should be "totally positive units".  An example of such a cubic field is $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3 - x^2 - 234x + 729$.  The unit group is $\langle -1,u,u'\rangle$ where $u = \alpha^2/9+8\alpha/9-4$ and $u' = -\alpha^2/9+\alpha/9+31$ are totally positive.  Then ${\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q}(\alpha-4) = 159 > 0$ but $\alpha-4$ is not a unit multiple of a totally positive element of $K$ since $\alpha-4$ and $-(\alpha-4)$ are not totally positive.

Comment: @KCd: thanks - done.