# Conjugation of integer matrices by $\mathrm{SL}_n \Bbb Z$ and narrowly equivalent ideal classes

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand K. Conrad's [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf) on the Latimer-MacDuffee theorem and related results.

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer with minimal polynomial $f$ of degree $n$. Let $M_f$ be the set of matrices in $M_n \Bbb Z$ with characteristic polynomial $f$.

The Latimer-MacDuffee theorem (Theorem 2.1 in the notes) establishes a bijection between the conjugation classes of matrices in $M_f$ and the ideal class monoid $ICM(\Bbb Z[\alpha])$ of $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$.

Namely, we send a fractional ideal $I$ to the matrix (in some $\Bbb Z$-basis $B$) associated to multiplication by $\alpha$, viewed as a $\Bbb Z$-linear map $L_\alpha \colon I \to I$.

In Remark 2.7 of the aforementioned notes, it is claimed that if we instead consider $SL_n \Bbb Z$ conjugacy classes of elements of $M_f$, then we need to replace the notion of equivalent ideals by *narrow equivalence* in the following sense: two fractional ideals $I$ and $J$ are narrowly equivalent if there exists $x \in \Bbb Q(\alpha)$ such that $N_{\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q}(x) > 0$ and $I = xJ$. (This is [not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500214/narrow-ideal-classes-and-totally-positive-elements) in general the relation defining the narrow class group.)

I think I have found a counterexample to the claim above, either that or I cannot find the error in my argument. I will first write a concrete counterexample, followed by the more general argument which I would like to proof-check.

If $\alpha = i$ and $f = X^2+1$, the norm of elements in $\Bbb Q(i)$ is always non-negative and $\Bbb Z[i]$ is the maximal order of $\Bbb Q(i)$. Thus, if the claim were true, $SL_2 \Bbb Z$-conjugacy classes of integer matrices satisfying $A^2 = -I$ should be in correspondence with $Cl(\Bbb Z[i]) = 0$. In other words, every two such matrices should be $SL_2 \Bbb Z$-conjugate.

However, if we put $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ any matrix $C = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ such that $CA = BC$ must satisfy $a=-d, b = c$ and so

$$\det(C) = -(a^2+b^2) \le 0.$$

Now the more general situation: suppose for simplicity that $O := \Bbb Z[\alpha]$ is the maximal order of $K:= \Bbb Q(\alpha)$. Put $PN(K)$ for the elements of positive norm of $K$ and $PN(O) = PN(K) \cap O$. Let $NCl(O)$ be the narrow class group in the aforementioned sense and $Cl(O)$ the usual class group.

There is an exact sequence

$$0 \to O^\times/PN(O) \hookrightarrow K^\times/PN(K) \to NCl(O) \to Cl(O) \to 0,$$

this follows from a similar argument that yields an exact sequence comparing $Cl(O)$ and the usual narrow class group (e.g. as noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3584968/362866)).

Now, $PN(K) = \ker(K^\times \xrightarrow{N} \Bbb Q^\times \xrightarrow{\mathrm{sgn}} \{-1,1\})$, hence $K^\times/PN(K)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_2 = \{-1,1\}$, it will be non-trivial only if there exists an element of negative norm. Likewise $O^\times/PN(O)$ will be either $G_2$ or $1$ depending on the existence of a norm $-1$ integral unit.

In particular, $NCl(O) = Cl(O)$ if and only if one of the following holds:

- 1. there exists $x \in O^\times$ of norm $-1$.
- 2. every element in $K^\times$ has positive norm.

If the claim of Remark 2.7 were true, then these conditions should characterize when the $SL_n \Bbb Z$ conjugation classes coincide with the $GL_n \Bbb Z$ ones.

However, I think the conjugation classes coincide only when (1) holds (hence the counterexample for $\Bbb Q(i)$).

The relevant direction (for the counterexample) argument is roughly as follows:

If $GL_n \Bbb Z$ and $SL_n \Bbb Z$ conjugacy classes coincide for a given matrix $A$, then $A$ and $DAD^{-1}$ for some matrix such that $\det D= -1$ are $SL_n \Bbb Z$ conjugate. Thus $A = (UD)A(UD)^{-1}$ for some $U$ such that $\det U = 1$. Hence $A$ commutes with a determinant $-1$ matrix.

Now suppose that there exists $A\in M_f$ such that its $GL_n \Bbb Z$ and $SL_n \Bbb Z$ conjugacy classes coincide. By the Latimer-MacDufee theorem,there exists $I$ a fractional ideal and $B$ a $\Bbb Z$-basis of $I$ such that $A$ is $GL_n \Bbb Z$ conjugate to $X := [L_\alpha \colon I \to I]_B$. By hypothesis $X$ and $A$ are $SL_n \Bbb Z$ conjugate. Thus the $SL_n \Bbb Z$ and $GL_n \Bbb Z$ conjugacy clases of $X$ also coincide since

$$(SL_n \Bbb Z) \cdot X = (SL_n \Bbb Z) \cdot A = (GL_n \Bbb Z) \cdot A = (GL_n \Bbb Z) \cdot X.$$

Thus it must exist $D$ such that $\det D = -1$ commuting with $X$. In basis $B$, this defines an $O$-linear iso $I \to I$, which must me multiplication by some $x \in K^\times$. In particular $-1 = \det D$ is the norm of $x$. Since $xI = I$, multiplying by $I^{-1}$ it follows that $x \in O^\times$.

I would very much appreciate a sanity check on whether my reasoning is correct and, if so, any comments on how one could compute the $SL_n  \Bbb Z$ conjugacy classes in terms of ideal classes.